# Rules for hybrid dragons? (mixed colors)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dragons

I run a campaign (Pathfinder mostly, with several house rules) in which I had an idea to incorporate a shadow/red dragon hybrid. It goes well with the story and the entire concept of the setting, but I was unable to find any official rules about mixing dragons of different colors and/or types.

So, if no such rules exist, what would be the easiest way of "mixing" these? And in case they do, where do I find them (preferably with an example or two).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There have been various suggestions for mixing dragons and creating hybrids, from [calculating average values for the hybrid](http://paizo.com/forums/gbihzec8/favorites?Mixed-Dragon-bloodlines) (adding up the values of the parents and dividing them by two etc) through [applying a colour theory of sorts (a blue and a yellow parent would produce a green offspring) and other solutions](http://paizo.com/paizo/messageboards/paizoPublishing/pathfinder/campaignSetting/general/archives/dragonsMatingWithDifferentColours) to [applying unofficial templates](http://www.purpleduckgames.com/dragon-hybrid-template) (such as I linked here).

I'd suggest checking the links for a more thorough discussion. :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I especially like the one from Purple Duck Games - it is simple and includes the traits of both parents.

Comment: Unfortunately the purple duck link is dead (good example of why link only answers are discouraged) and does not exist on Wayback Machine. Anyone have the linked information stored somewhere?

Answer (score 11):

If the issue of making the dragon more powerful isn't an issue (either you can scale down to a lower age category or your PCs can handle the new CR) you can use the half-dragon template in Pathfinder on a dragon.  At all but the lowest age categories, the resulting dragon leans more toward one side than the other, since the half-dragon template's abilities don't scale as much with age, but this can be a good thing.  I think OpaCitizen's options are more thorough, but this option can be taken with nothing but Bestiary 1, no house rules, no third party supplements.

Comment: I know this is a necro, but I only just saw this question :D I hope my very late answer helps anyway.

Comment: No such thing as necroing on SE, so no need to apologise

Comment: Remember, [the Stack likes new quality answers no matter how old the question](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1344/4398).

Comment: The 3.5 half-dragon template can *also* be applied to dragons. Actually, the two templates are most likely nearly identical; I haven’t actually checked half-dragon specifically, but most things from *Monster Manual* were just updated for changes in the rules from 3.5 to Pathfinder, not redesigned entirely.

Comment: @KRyan - huh, so it can.  I thought the 3.5 version stated "living, non-dragon creature" but the d20 srd says I'm wrong.  Thanks.