# What is this book or homebrew PDF covering how to stat offspring from different dragon parents that I remember?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, product-identification, dragons

I am new here, but I have read some of your discussions and I see that there is a glimmer of hope for me, for I cannot remember where I have seen information on this particular matter.

To rephrase: **I would like to make a dragon that is an offspring of different coloured/typed dragons;** say, one is chromatic and the other is metallic, or both are different chromatic kinds. I already know that I can apply a half-dragon template to a dragon. That is not what I am looking for. 
A few years ago I have seen some published (electronically or in paper, not sure) source that contained information that I require. It might have been an unofficial .pdf (open licensed d20), or some sort of compendium with creatures and templates, but I remember it specifically addressed the issue and it even **had a "fancy" name** for such creatures.

Can anyone, please, drop me a hint? Pretty please!

[looks innocent as a baby kobold hugging a golden pony]

Comment: Mindwin – thanks, done it!
@KRyan – It is written in my question that I am not looking for a half-dragon applied to a dragon. It also says that I am looking for a source on the topic, that covers it in full and that I cannot find it. It is not a matter of preferrence, it is a matter of finding the source, the rules, and the name for such creatures :)

Comment: And as for the approach I don't like it because it does not do justice to both parents. They are basically one kind of dragon with some useless stuff from the other type. The approach I am looking for was quite profound and had a good story to it.

Comment: Related:  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13584/rules-for-hybrid-dragons-mixed-colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might have been [The Slayer's Guide To Dragons](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=3975) (3.0, Mongoose Publishing, authored by one G. Gygax who also wrote a few things for TSR ;-) It had rules for dragon-dragon hybrids; I think it covered all the chromatic-chromatic combinations but I don't recall whether it included metal/metal or metal/chromatic.

If it jogs your memory, I remember it had russet dragons (red-green hybrid) and pink (red-white). As well as the hybrids, it also had a suggestion for albino red dragons as a way to mess with players.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not sure if this is exactly what I had seen (I do not have the book at hand at the moment) but certainly it's what I hoping to get! Once again, many thanks! :)

Comment: I'm not sure how much detail it had on hybrids, but hopefully it'll be some help!

Answer (score -3):

The official way to accomplish this is to use the half-dragon template on a dragon. So a half-green red dragon would be born of parents that were a green dragon and a red dragon. I am reasonably certain there is no official alternative to this approach.

I cannot claim to know what unofficial options exist for this.

Comment: Not a complete answer, since I don’t know where to find what is being sought, but this does at least give people information on where this *isn’t*.

Comment: I think what you are talking about is _Creatures That Cannot Be II_ [ http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/eo/20070401a ]

Comment: @Lazurite I mean, I am talking about any dragons anywhere, and the *Monster Manual* half-dragon template. Don’t need a web article to confirm that it works (and *Races of the Dragon* doesn’t get to change a *Monster Manual* template).

Comment: Actually, it does. RotD says that you cannot add a half-dragon template to a dragon (p. 72). 
The article appeals to some higher authority, which allows it, though.

Comment: @Lazurite That is my point: no matter what *Races of the Dragon* says on the subject, it lacks the **authority** to make that change. The errata rules are clear on this point.

Comment: _RotD_ lacks the authority? Yeah, I would think so too :)

Comment: @Lazurite Actually, KRyan is correct on this point. According to the policy established by WotC a supplement is not permitted to be considered errata, and when there is a conflict between a primary source and a secondary source, then the primary source always wins; and thus RotD does not have the "authority" to change the content of a primary source (MM1) as a primary source always overrides a secondary supplement. A policy with WotC has ignored with some frequently, sadly. But still technically correct. So RotD basically wasted ink printing what it did.

Comment: @nijineko Actually, I have alreagy agreed with KRyan, but thanks for the additional piece of information :) It's always appreciated :) 
EDIT: Would you mind giving the source to that policy? (I do think I might need that :D)

Comment: @Lazurite Rules Compendium, page 5. I do believe that there is also a previous statement regarding the primacy of the Core 3 over other sources, but I don't recall where that was written off the top of my head.

Comment: @Lazurite Also the beginning of every (? most, anyway) errata document explains how to handle contradictions between source books. It’s quite specific that the “primary source” wins out. *Monster Manual* is the primary source for the half-dragon template.