# What happens when a metallic dragon and a chromatic dragon mate?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, dragons

Is it possible, and if so, what happens when a metallic and chromatic dragon mate? I'm most interested in blue and bronze dragons.

I'm interested in lore from all editions except the fourth edition.  This question is for a specific campaign of mine.  General information about lore of dragon breeding habits are also interesting, but in particular:

1. both what kind of offspring is producing
2. what kind of lineage would follow for its own offspring?

Comment: How far beyond "the earth moves" or "the flying gets erratic" do you need this answer to go?

Comment: Related question on [How long are the life phases of a dragon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113308/how-long-are-the-life-phases-of-a-dragon)

Comment: Related: [Rules for Hybrid Dragons Mixed Colors](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13584/rules-for-hybrid-dragons-mixed-colors)

Comment: The offspring of a blue dragon and a gold dragon has a hide that can be fashioned into a very confusing dress.

Answer (score 53):

#### A unique and highly unusual new dragon offspring, who is typically sterile

The D&D 3.5 sourcebook *Draconomicon* (2003), p.27 asserts that dragons of different types can produce hybrid offspring:

> Crossbreeds between dragon species are not unknown, but very rare. A hybrid dragon of this sort is usually left to fend for itself, but on occasion both parents (if they are on good terms with each other) might watch over it until it reaches adulthood.

The AD&D 2e *Draconomicon* (1990), p.64 describes that chromatic dragons can interbreed. The majority of such creatures are infertile, and therefore do not continue to produce offspring. Their coloration is a blend of the parents' color, and many other attributes are a half-way between the two parents, such as size and other details of physical appearance.

The breath weapon of a cross-breed dragon is usually that of one of its parents, but sometimes it is a combination of the two. They tend to learn the behavioural patterns of the parent who raises them.

The result of two metallic dragons breeding are more unpredictable and sometimes bizarre. These are rarer, with most interbreeding taking place between chromatic dragons (*Draconomicon* (1990), p.12).

Crossbreeds between metallic and chromatic dragons are extremely rare, but are known to happen. Their traits are highly variable and unpredictable, even more so than the offspring of two metallic dragons.

Bronze dragons particularly mate for life, and take courtship and mating very seriously, making a bronze hybrid less likely, but they care for their offspring with dedication. Blue dragons similarly have elaborate courtship rituals and care for their eggs (*Draconomicon* (2003), p.40), so a hybrid between these two types of dragon may well survive to adulthood. The exact traits, however, are unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will use this lore. But I have to change something because the hybrid dragon is the Parent of one of my NPCs.

Comment: @C.G.Hellishscythe if you want to create a stat block for the child of the hybrid dragon (assuming the hybrid mated with a humanoid), I'll refer you to the "Half-Dragon" template in the Monster Manual. It's also meant for a "pureblooded" dragon parent, but it might still help you out (maybe even if your NPC isn't a Half-Dragon, since the stat block highlights the aspects most central to the offspring of dragons)

Comment: @C.G.Hellishscythe Note that not all hybrid dragons are sterile, only most of them. Some can produce offspring, and dragons in general can (according to the 2003 Draconomicon) procreate with just about any species.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard They would appear to be, breeding wise, the equivalent of an omnivore.

Comment: "Crossbreeds between metallic and chromatic dragons are extremely rare, but are known to happen. Their traits are highly variable and unpredictable, even more so than the more common chromatic crossbreeds." - Did you mean metallic there, rather than chromatic?

Comment: @PixelMaster, it was almost correct assumptions about the child of the hybrid dragon. it was Half dragon and Eladrin. so I don't know the fey ancestry, affect the child.

Comment: @C.G.Hellishscythe If this answered your question, please accept this answer.